# How to I convert normal php function into codeigniter function

Tags: php

Here is the normal php function which is used in codeigniter which uploads the picture from an android device. I want someone to help to convert into codeigniter function to make it work.

```
private function uploadImages(){

    //get the data from the $_POST and $_FILES
    $postKeyPairs = $_POST;
    $files = $_FILES['files'];

    $titles = "";$description = "";

    //fetch the titles
    if(array_key_exists('title',$postKeyPairs)){
        $titles = $postKeyPairs['title'];
    }
    //get the description
    if(array_key_exists('description',$postKeyPairs)){
        $description = $postKeyPairs['description'];
    }

    //the root file path for the uploaded images
    $file_path = "uploads/";

    //count the number of files to upload
    for($i = 0; $i < count($files['name']); $i++){

        //make sure the filename is unique
        $filename = basename($files['name'][$i]);

        //get the proper filepath for the individual files
        $file_path = $file_path.$filename;

        //get the title for the current image
        if(isset($titles[$i]) && $titles[$i] != null){
            $imageTitle = $titles[$i];
        }
        else{
            $imageTitle = "NA";
        }

        //and get the image description
        if(isset($description[$i]) && $description[$i] != null){
            $imageDescp = $description[$i];
        }
        else{
            $imageDescp = "NA";
        }

        //upload the file into the file system
        if(!move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'][$i], $file_path)){
            //any exception occurs
            throw new Exception("Couldn't upload image ".$files['name'][$i]);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: you said it already works in codeigniter, How do you mean convert into codeigniter function? Please, expatiate on your requirements.

Comment: I mean... Like in CodeIgniter $this->upload->do_upload(); function uploads the data. I want to use that type of methods to use. not the normal php in codeigniter... Thank you in advance

Comment: What you are referring to is Object-Oriented programming, it has nothing to do with Codeigniter function. Look it up from internet and see what is object oriented programming